# How to create a custom error page on pivotal tc server

Tags: jsp, spring-tool-suite, custom-error-pages

I am programming a Webshop for a project in University. 
I use the Spring Tool Suite 3.9.5 with a Pivotal tc Server Developer v4.0.

I'm using servlets in combination with jsp-files, the Servlets are stored in Project/src/src(package) and the jsps in Project/WebContent

Now i wrote this into the web.xml of the server:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/FestMe/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/FestMe/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

This replaced the standard tomcat Error 404 page with a browser-specific, but it doesn't display my created 404.jsp, any ideas how to change that?